# Serialization Java: which classes need to "implement Serializable"?

Tags: java, serialization

so I know I could probably figure it out eventually, but I couldn't really find a topic that answers this seemingly simple question.

I am serializing a vector of a set of objects, with each such object pertaining to one user-defined class.  I know vectors are serializable.  Do I also have to make the user-defined class implement serializable?  And, each of these user-defined classes contains other user-defined classes.  Do those have to be labeled as implementing Serializable as well?  (and so on, or do just the top-level class need to implement Serializable)?

(Forget noting that arrayLists should be used instead of vectors, I've heard that before, I'm practicing because I hear vectors are good for multithreading.  I found topics that discuss similar stuff, but not precisely this)

Thanks

Comment: Actually, Vector is more or less deprecated. If you want a thread-safe List, `Collections.synchronizedList` is better. Or just manually synchronize on the list, since you'll probably need to do that anyway to avoid race conditions on writes.

Comment: alright, thanks, good to know.  I first learned C++, hence my use of vectors.  is vector deprecated there too, in C++?

Comment: I haven't written C++ since the 20th century, sorry. :)

Comment: @squirrelsareduck Just thought I'd mention that I was learning C++ just last year and data structures such as Linked Lists and Vectors were being taught as part of the main content as if they were still completely viable solutions to a number of different problems. They each have their uses for reducing the amount of time taken to access certain elements since they're constructed differently on the inside. I'm not sure that you would need to delve so deep into this for Java development but for C++ development it seems more crucial.

Comment: ^^^^ learned it at university, by the way

Comment: Just in case it needs to be said: if you're extending a class that already declares that it implements `Serializable`, there's no need for the subclass to declare that also. Though I suppose it wouldn't hurt.

Comment: However, it looks like every such class must declare a `serialVersionUID`, it doesn't get inherited. But even then, you might run into deserialization problems...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: Anything being serialized, including all classes referred to by fields (instance variables), must implement [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), *or* the field must be [`transient`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient).

In your case, the user defined class must implement `Serializable`, and have fields whose type is `Serializable`. This applies recursively, so fields of the class of the fields must also be `Serializable`, etc.

The `transient` keyword tells the serialization mechanism to ignore the field for the purposes of serialization.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`Serializable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) documentation:

> When traversing a graph, an object may be encountered that does not support the Serializable interface. In this case the NotSerializableException will be thrown and will identify the class of the non-serializable object.

So yes, all objects referenced by the vector, directly and indirectly, will need to be `Serializable`, unless of course they're marked as [`transient`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transient_%28computer_programming%29).

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can implement a custom Vector with custom serialization and serialize non-serializable objects, like here

```
class Y {
    int y;
    Y(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class X implements Serializable {
    transient Y y;

    private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream os) throws IOException {
        os.defaultWriteObject();
        os.writeInt(y.y);
    }

    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream is) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        is.defaultReadObject();
        y = new Y(is.readInt());
    }
...
```